# How to save streaming video data from MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, caching, mpmovieplayercontroller, avplayer

My app supports both online and offline mode. Also it plays video(from server) by using `MPMoviePlayerController`.

As my app supports offline mode i would like to save the video content while it is playing so that i can play it from locally when user connected to the no network.

I searched lot but i am not able to find appropriate answer. If anybody knows can you please let me know what is the right approach to do this?

Here i don't wish to use two separate threads to download and stream the video, i am looking forward for a answer which will save the streaming data in the disk or cache.

Comment: I've worked on something like this before. It's not easy and I can't remember exactly how to do it. You can try writing your own `NSURLProtocol` subclass to see if you can get the data that way. You can also try running all the calls through a local server, and get the local server to cache the data.